# Powershell on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch-file

I execute a bat file from command prompt passing it 2 fully qualified names (this is for PGP) and it runs fine.

When I execute the same bat file from Powershell passing it the same names, it runs and produces the output but gives a message "The system cannot find the path specified".

In cmd :

```
mybatfile.bat e:\dirname\filename.ext  e:\dirname\filename.ext
```

In PS :

```
./mybatfile e:\dirname\filename.ext  e:\dirname\filename.ext
```

the bat file is like this:

```
@echo off
c:
cd users\username
set inputfile=%1
set outputfile=%2

pgp --encrypt %inputfile% --recipient keyid --output %outputfile% --overwrite remove
```

Comment: Remove the `@echo off` and see if that gives you any clues.

Comment: Where are you in the file system when you run these commands? Where is the batch file? Is the batch file on your `PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your fault is to not give an absolut path, so if your current folder is somewhere deeper in the c: drive your code tries to cd from there to folder users\username which isn't present there.
BTW you should always double quote pathes possibly containing spaces or other poisenous chars.

```
@echo off
cd /D "C:\users\username"
set "inputfile=%~1"
set "outputfile=%~2"

pgp --encrypt "%inputfile%" --recipient keyid --output "%outputfile%" --overwrite remove
```